# separate colors in plot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a `geom_tile` plot with different colors and each one represent a value in the data.

I want to separate each range of colors in the plot by a line in a color different from the plot colors.

```
e.g(-0.5<=0<0.5 colored red)
e.g(0<0.5<1 colored blue)
```

Can this be done in R?

i need these ranges to be separated by a line on geom_tile.
Thanks in advance.

Comment: @Joris Meys : hello , i edited the question and make it more clear , but i don't know what you meant with (reproducible example) , thanks

Comment: make some dummy data, make a plot as you have it now, and tell us what you want more clearly. eg: `x <- matrix(rnorm(100),ncol=10) ; contour(x)` (which is not what you want, but I don't really understand what you're heading at)

Comment: @Joris Meys : i already have a plot , how can i show it to you in order to help me ??

Comment: use the image icon and upload the file. If possible, make sure you add code we can run *without the need of having your data* to reconstruct the plot. That will make it a lot easier. See the example of Richie below, that's what we call a minimal reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

Use the `colour` argument to change the colour of the borders.

An example adapted from one on `?geom_tile`.

```
pp <- function (n,r=4) {
      x <- seq(-r*pi, r*pi, len=n)
      df <- expand.grid(x=x, y=x)
      df$r <- sqrt(df$x^2 + df$y^2)
      df$z <- cos(df$r^2)*exp(-df$r/6)
      df
     }
p <- ggplot(pp(20), aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = z), colour = "black")
p
```

Or did you mean "I want to specify the fill colours for different groups of tiles".  One way to do this is to convert the fill variable to be a factor and call `scale_fill_manual`.

```
dfr <- pp(20)
dfr$discrete_z <- cut(dfr$z, c(-1, 0, 1)) # makes z a factor

p <- ggplot(dfr, aes(x=x,y=y)) + 
  geom_tile(aes(fill = discrete_z)) + 
  scale_fill_manual(
    values = c("red", "blue")
  )
p
```

Comment: thanks for your reply , that's approximately what i want , what you wrote change the border colors for all the tiles , what i want to do is to specify a range of tiles(based on range of values)  and give them a border color , is this can be done?